# Using Curl commands in Ruby on Rails 2

Tags: xml, http, curl, ruby-on-rails-2

I am wanting to send some XML files over HTTP to a web service in post request. I have the generated XML files and would like to use the following command

```
curl -F "SUBMISSION=@submission.xml" -F "STUDY=@study.xml" \
     -F "SAMPLE=@sample.xml" https://www.somesite.com/submit
```

I have no clue how to incorporate the command in Rails 2.

Please could so one suggest me an idea or library that I could use for this purpose.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Curb gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/curb), it is a library that wraps cURL in Ruby objects and methods.

Have a look at the examples on http://taf2.github.com/curb/.

In your case you will have to use something like

```
submission_field = Curl::PostField.content(File.read('submission.xml'), 'SUBMISSION')
study_field = Curl::PostField.content(File.read('stydy.xml'), 'STUDY')

c = Curl::Easy.http_post("https://www.somesite.com/submit",
                         submission_field, study_field, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you Gioele for the reply, but wouldn't the code be
c = Curl::Easy.http_post("https://www.somesite.com/submit", submission_field, study_field, ...)

Comment: Yes, wrote that in a hurry :)